# Can I compare a key in both a Db2 table and file in mainframe?

Tags: mainframe

I have a student id as the primary key in both the db2 table and file which consists of various records in the mainframe. if the key matches in both the db2 table and file then I have to move that record into output file-1. How can i do this?

Comment: what do you mean file?  VSAM, PS, or other format

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How you can do this? Write a program. Show us what you did *if* you don't succeed.

Comment: @Hogstrom PS file

Comment: @cschneid I have tried to sort the records in both file and table but i dont know the procedure to compare a file and table

Answer (score 1):

I second comments expecting OP to show progress, ask specific Qs. At least share input/output examples, failed attempts, type & definition of a problem (JCL, programming, Db2,...). But maybe this is a case of not knowing where to start - not that uncommon in the Mainframe universe. If that's it, then here's me making a bunch of assumptions :)

Db2 data lives in tables. But you can **put relevant data into a dataset**. Use Db2 utilities like [UNLOAD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=utilities-unload), [sample DSNTEP* programs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=dpasp-dsntep2-dsntep4-sample-programs), [DSNTIAUL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=dpasp-dsntiaul-sample-program), vendor tools, in-house tools & programs and so on. This would make it a 2 step process in JCL:

```
{{jobcard}}                                                                   
//*                                                                           
//* Get relevant data from Db2 into a dataset                                 
//*                                                                           
//RUNTEP2 EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,DYNAMNBR=20                                       
//STEPLIB  DD DISP=SHR,DSN={{DB2_HLQ}}.SDSNLOAD                               
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN={{DB2_HLQ}}.RUNLIB.LOAD                            
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*                                                        
//SYSTSIN  DD *                                                               
 DSN SYSTEM({{DB2_SSID}})                                                     
 RUN  PROGRAM(DSNTIAUL) PLAN(DSNTIAUL) PARMS('SQL,10') -                      
      LIB('{{DB2_HLQ}}.RUNLIB.LOAD')                                          
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                        
//SYSUDUMP DD SYSOUT=*                                                        
//SYSREC00 DD DSNAME=&&ROWS,DISP=(NEW,PASS),UNIT=SYSDA                        
//SYSPUNCH DD DUMMY                                                           
//SYSIN    DD *                                                               
 Select EMPNO From {{SCHEMA}}.EMP                                             
   Where  LASTNAME In ('HAAS', 'YOSHIMURA');                                  
/*                                                                            
//*                                                                           
//* In case of the sample EMP table, you should end up with 2 EMPNOs in       
//* SYSREC00:                                                                 
//*   000010      <- HAAS                                                     
//*   000170      <- YOSHIMURA                                                
//*                                                                           
//* Use DFSORT to perform a join.                                         
//*                                                                           
//SORT    EXEC PGM=SORT                                                       
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                        
//SORTJNF1 DD *                                                               
000000 spam                          -                                        
000010 qualifying row 1/2            +                                        
000090 spam                          -                                        
000170 qualifying row 2/2            +                                        
000900 eggs                          -                                        
//SORTJNF2 DD DSNAME=&&ROWS,DISP=SHR                                          
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                                        
//SYSIN    DD *                                                               
* Control statements for JOINKEYS application                                 
 JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,6,A)                                              
 JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(1,6,A)                                              
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,70)                                                    
* Control statements for main task (joined records)                           
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                                                             
/*
```

Here's a snippet of what you get in SORTOUT:

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA ***
000010 qualifying row 1/2            +           
000170 qualifying row 2/2            +           
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA *
```

Alternatively, write a **script on Mainframe** with REXX, Java, Python, Node,... , a DFSORT exit. Or **script off-mainframe** with whatever you feel most comfortable with that can handle basic database & FTP/SSH/HTTP(zOSMF). You can, say, do it all in Jupyter with Python & ibm_db_dbi. I'm not suggesting you do that, but, assuming this is a general "how" question - it's one of the ways too.

Script approach does not have to go Db2->Dataset->Process->Dataset. Load file data into Db2 instead. Aggregate, join,... with SQL rather than sort, sets, intersections or whatever you'd go for in a script.